# How can I programmatically generate the .bin file containing macros in Office documents

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I need to generate the .bin file that contains the VBA macro part of a Microsoft Word file programmatically. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but it will be some work. You basically will have to implement the following specification:

> **[[MS-OVBA]: Office VBA File Format Structure Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313094%28office.12%29.aspx)**

Comment: Thanks,
:) . Isnt there a simpler way to get started :)

Comment: @francis: You might try adding the macros to a Word document programmatically using Word's object model, then save the document and extract the bin part.